# Transform Word into Icon in Angular

Tags: html, angular, icons, font-awesome

I'm have a page that the footer contains a lot of info of a gym, Contact, Location etc...

The gym i picked for example contains 5 means of contact, that are:

- Commercial Phone
- Whatsapp
- Instagram
- Facebook
- Email

This is how the json look like:

```
"ExibirContatos": [
                {
                    "ID_TipoContato": "2",
                    "TipoDescricao": "Telefone comercial",
                    "Contato": "(31)2523-0672"
                },
                {
                    "ID_TipoContato": "9",
                    "TipoDescricao": "Whatsapp",
                    "Contato": "(31)98428-6287"
                },
                {
                    "ID_TipoContato": "5",
                    "TipoDescricao": "Instagram",
                    "Contato": "@br_fit_"
                },
                {
                    "ID_TipoContato": "7",
                    "TipoDescricao": "Facebook",
                    "Contato": "https://www.facebook.com/brfitbh/"
                },
                {
                    "ID_TipoContato": "4",
                    "TipoDescricao": "E-mail",
                    "Contato": "contato@brfitbh.com.br"
                }
            ]
```

TS:

```js
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

import { Academia } from '../../classes/academia';

interface AcademiaRequest {
  ACADEMIA_INFO: any;
}

export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {

  academia: Academia = new Academia();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.receberAcademia(this.academia);
  }

  receberAcademia(academia) {
    this.http
      .get<AcademiaRequest>(
        'http://fitgroup.com.br/vysor_vendas_online/fg_vendas.php?AuthToken=FlnPoU230xGF&Metodo=academiaLoad&IDCliente=000949'
      )
      .subscribe(response => {
        academia.nome = response.ACADEMIA_INFO.AcademiaDados.NomeAcademia;
        academia.rua = response.ACADEMIA_INFO.AcademiaDados.EnderecoLogradouro;
        academia.numero = response.ACADEMIA_INFO.AcademiaDados.EnderecoNumero;
        academia.cep = response.ACADEMIA_INFO.AcademiaDados.EnderecoCEP;
        academia.cidade = response.ACADEMIA_INFO.AcademiaDados.EnderecoCidade;
        academia.estado = response.ACADEMIA_INFO.AcademiaDados.EnderecoUF;
        academia.contatos = response.ACADEMIA_INFO.VendasOnline.ExibirContatos;
      });
  }
}
```

Academia Class:

```js
export class Academia {

  registros: number;
  nome: string;

  // Endereço

  rua: string;
  numero: string;
  cep: string;
  cidade: string;
  estado: string;

  // Contato

  contatos: any[];
}
```

And for last, my HTML:

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mt-2 mb-4">
   <h5 class="mb-4 ml-4 font-weight-bold">
      CONTATO:
   </h5>
   <ul class="f-address">
      <li *ngFor="let contatos of academia.contatos">
         <p> {{contatos.TipoDescricao }}: {{ contatos.Contato }} </p>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

It's printing something like that:

[image: Result]

But i don't want the name of the contact, i don't want "Telefone Comercial:", "Whatsapp" and etc... I want these names to be replaced by icons, fontawesome icons, these icons respectively:

1. `<i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>`
2. `<i class="fas fa-whatsapp"></i>`
3. `<i class="fas fa-instagram"></i>`
4. `<i class="fas fa-facebook"></i>`
5. `<i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>`

But i don't have any ideas how to do such a conversion, i even have thinked in this code:

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mt-2 mb-4">
      <h5 class="mb-4 ml-4 font-weight-bold">
            CONTATO:
      </h5>
      <ul class="f-address">
            <li *ngFor="let contatos of academia.contatos">
                  <p> <i class="fas {{ contatos.TipoDescricao }}"></i> {{ contatos.Contato }} </p>
            </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

But first i need to convert to the rest of the icon's name "fa-icon_name", how can i do that? Please help me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see two ways to solve this:

1 - Create a method to get the icon correspondent to the description, but it would impact the performance as it would be called on every change.

2 - Create a pipe, which is the recommended way:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

// Note that I have used Font Awesome 5.x for this demo.
const descriptionIconClassMapper = {
  'E-mail': 'fas fa-envelope',
  'Telefone comercial': 'fas fa-phone-alt',
  Facebook: 'fab fa-facebook',
  Instagram: 'fab fa-instagram',
  Whatsapp: 'fab fa-whatsapp'
};

@Pipe({
  name: 'descriptionToIconClass'
})
export class DescriptionToIconClassPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform<T extends keyof typeof descriptionIconClassMapper>(
    description: T
  ): typeof descriptionIconClassMapper[T] {
    return descriptionIconClassMapper[description];
  }
}
```

And in HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mt-2 mb-4">
  <h5 class="mb-4 ml-4 font-weight-bold">
    CONTATO:
  </h5>

  <ul class="f-address" *ngIf="academiaInfo$ | async as academiaInfo">
    <li *ngFor="let contato of academiaInfo.VendasOnline.ExibirContatos">
      <p><i class="mr-1" [ngClass]="contato.TipoDescricao | descriptionToIconClass"></i>{{ contato.Contato }}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

**Some tips**:

1 - Do not call *http* requests directly from *components*. Create a *service* to wrap this;

2 - Instead of `subscribe`, prefer to use `async` *pipe* for `GET` requests;

3 - Instead of using `any`, you can use a tool to generate typescript interfaces from a JSON, like http://jsontots.com.

4 - Unless you have a good reason to use `class`, prefer `interfaces`, as it wouldn't affect build size.

5 - [**See the DEMO :)**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-issue-repro2-igmeel)

Comment: Oh, thanks, worked just fine!

Hey, i don't know if it's allowed here to ask for some way to talk to you, because i could use a lot of your help, if ok foryou.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pipe to achieve that. Create a pipe that takes your `contatos.TipoDescricao` as an input and returns the matching icon for that.

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'descriptionToIcon'
})
export class DescriptionToIconPipe implements PipeTransform {

  private static readonly iconsForDescriptions:Array<{desc:string, icon:string}> = [
    {desc: 'Telefone comercial', icon: 'fa-phone-alt'},
    // Add all other texts and icons as pairs as well
  ]

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    return DescriptionToIconPipe.iconsForDescriptions.find(item => item.desc === value).icon;
  }

}
```

And in your HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mt-2 mb-4">
      <h5 class="mb-4 ml-4 font-weight-bold">
            CONTATO:
      </h5>
      <ul class="f-address">
            <li *ngFor="let contatos of academia.contatos">
                  <p> <i class="fas {{ contatos.TipoDescricao | descriptionToIcon}}"></i> {{ contatos.Contato }} </p>
            </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```